# What is a good way to implement actioncable channels inside an engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to implement an action cable inside a rails engine, I can't find any documentation regarding how actioncable relates to rails engines.

I'd like to know:
a.) Should I implement my own ::ApplicationCable::Connection? 
b.) Or should I just implement channels and expect the host application to handle the connection implementation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky; I've rubbed up against the same problem and opted to throw out ActionCable. Assuming you need to actually use it here, are you planning on using it on pages rendered by your engine exclusively? If so, you should be able to wire everything up "normally" with your own `::ApplicationCable::Connection` in the engine as you mentioned.